# determine if intersection of a set with conjunction of two other sets is empty

Tags: algorithm, set, specifications, set-theory

For any three given sets A, B and C: is there a way to determine (programmatically) whether there is an element of A that is part of the conjunction (edit: intersection) of B and C?

example:
A: all numbers greater than 3
B: all numbers lesser than 7
C: all numbers that equal 5

In this case there is an element in set A, being the number 5,  that fits. I'm implementing this as specifications, so this numerical range is just an example. A, B, C could be anything.

Comment: Are your sets subsets of the integers ?  Or something more general ?  If the latter, how do you represent your sets ?

Comment: @High Performance Mark, they are not represented by something. Unless you count a Specification class as a representation: martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf  -> I trying to implement partial subsumption and googling etc brought me to set theory. If I'm in a wrong area please tell me.

Comment: I guess I'm desperately trying to find some anchor point to finally solve some set of related problems.

Comment: @Koen: I fail to understand how you intend (or even conceive the possibility of) determining anything at all programmatically without a representation accessible to a program.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just compute the intersection of the three sets and check to see if it's empty?

Comment: @niki, the reason is I use specifications (maybe I went looking in the wrong direction looking for help in set theory) and the intersection of of two specicifactions may return the same conjunction. Eg the two specifications GreaterThan2 and LesserThan5 will return the composite AndSpecification again with GreaterThan2 and LesserThan5.

Comment: @High Performance Mark, I'm not really sure I know what you mean by representation. The 'sets' (specifications) are objects. I'm trying to find ways they can determine between themselves whether one is a special case of a conjuction of two others. The composite specification is giving me troubles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Thanks Niki!

It will be helpful if `B.Count <= C.Count <= A.Count`.

```
D = GetCommonElements(B,C);
if( D.Count>0 && GetCommonElements(D,A).Count >0)
{
    // what you want IS NOT EMPTY
}
else
{
    // what you want IS EMPTY
}

SET GetCommonElements(X,Y)
{
    common = {}
    for x in X:
       if Y.Contains(x):
         common.Add(x);
    return common;
}
```

Look at [**Efficient Set Intersection Algorithm**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497338/efficient-set-intersection-algorithm).

---

We can use [**distributive laws of sets**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets)

[image]

```
if(HasCommonElements(A,B) || HasCommonElements(A,C))
{
    // what you want IS NOT EMPTY
}
else
{
    // what you want IS EMPTY
}
```

```
bool HasCommonElements(X,Y)
{
    // if at least one common element is found return true(immediately)

    return false
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, conjunction essentially means intersection not union.

Comment: Thanks Niki! Then problem reduces to finding A ^ B ^ C.

Comment: @Niki:  It looks ambiguous to me, and TheMachineCharmer has misinterpreted it the same way I did when I read the question.  It would be better to use the exact term.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to programmatically compute the intersection of 3 sets, right?  You want to see if there is an element in A that exists in the intersection of B and C, or in other words, you want to know if the intersection of A, B and C is non-empty.

Many languages have set containers and intersection algorithms so you should just be able to use those.  Your example in OCaml:

```
module Int = struct
    type t = int
    let compare i j = if i<j then -1 else if i=j then 0 else 1
end;;

module IntSet = Set.Make(Int);;

let a = List.fold_left (fun a b -> IntSet.add b a) IntSet.empty [4;5;6;7;8;9;10];;
let b = List.fold_left (fun a b -> IntSet.add b a) IntSet.empty [0;1;2;3;4;5;6];;
let c = IntSet.add 5 IntSet.empty;;

let aIbIc = IntSet.inter (IntSet.inter b c) a;;
IntSet.is_empty aIbIc;;
```

This outputs false, as the intersection of a b and c is non-empty (contains 5).  This of course relies on the fact that the elements of the set are comparable (in the example, the function compare defines this property in the Int module).

Alternatively in C++:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>

int main()
{
    std::set<int> A, B, C;

    for(int i=10; i>3; --i)
        A.insert(i);
    for(int i=0; i<7; ++i)
        B.insert(i);
    C.insert(5);

    std::set<int> ABC, BC;
    std::set_intersection(B.begin(), B.end(), C.begin(), C.end(), std::inserter(BC, BC.begin()));
    std::set_intersection(BC.begin(), BC.end(), A.begin(), A.end(), std::inserter(ABC, ABC.begin()));

    for(std::set<int>::iterator i = ABC.begin(); i!=ABC.end(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << *i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question needs further clarification.
First, do you want to work with symbolic sets given by a range?
And secondly, is it a one time question or is it going to be repeated in some form (if yes, what are the stable parts of the question?)?

If you want to work with ranges, then you could represent these with binary trees and define union and intersection operations on these structures. Building the tree would require O(n log n) and finding the result would require O(log n). This would not pay off with only tree sets, but it would be flexible to efficiently support any combination of ranges (if that is what you thought by 'it can be anything').

On the other hand if anything means, any set of elements, then the only option is to enumerate elements. In this case building B+ trees on sets B and C will also require O(n log n) time, but here n is the number of elements, and in the first case n is the number of ranges. The later might be several orders of magnitude bigger and of course it can represent only finite number of elements.