# How do I get the intersection between two arrays as a new array?

Tags: java, c++, c, algorithm

I faced this problem many times during various situations. It is generic to all programming languages although I am comfortable with C or Java.

Let us consider two arrays (or collections):

```
char[] A = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
char[] B = {'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
```

How do I get the common elements between the two arrays as a new array?
In this case, the intersection of array A and B is `char[] c = {'c', 'd'}`.

I want to avoid the repeated iteration of one array inside the other array which will
increase the execution time by (length of A times length of B) which is too much in the case of huge arrays.

Is there any way we could do a single pass in each array to get the common elements?

Comment: Sort the arrays first. Then you only need a single pass.

Comment: As stated above, sort the two arrays, and from there it is really easy.

Comment: Let Us Consider Sorting Cannot Be Implemented In This Case (I am saying so because in most day to day case it will take longer time to sort non-primitive data types or classes which would suppress the purpose of single pass).

Comment: Use HashSet to store all data from first array.  Then for every element in the second array, check if the HashSet contains() the element.  The complexity of sorting is O(n lg n) while the complexity of this method is O(n)

Comment: is sorting allowed at all, or do u have to work the array is it is? because this feels like a string searching algorithm question

Comment: Well, I guess sorting is doing several passes over the array, so to me this option should be excluded.

Comment: What is more important to you? Time or space efficiency?

Comment: @RanjanSarma Sorting, then merging is `O(n lg n)`.  Using unsorted arrays is `O(n^2)`.  Sorting will be a lot more efficient.

Comment: Is the type of the arrays actually `char`? Some of the arguments in comments below could be resolved by putting some restrictions on the types. For example, all the stuff about expected `O(N)` with hash tables goes out the window if you don't have a reasonable hash function for the type (that's why Java encourages you to write one). Conversely with `char` and sufficiently large input, the fastest could be to create an array with one element for each character value (generally 256 or 65536), and use it to record which characters appear in each input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficient set intersection algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497338/efficient-set-intersection-algorithm)

Comment: Do you care about duplicates? IE if A: [1,1,2] and B: [1,2], should the intersection be [1]?

Comment: Without a clear definition of what "best" is, I propose this solution for sorting arrays: Print each array item on a slip of paper, and place each slip of paper in a clearly marked envelope. Mail the envelopes to your grandmother with instructions to return only the items that were included in both envelopes, along with some cookies. The solution isn't very fast as it's `O(USPS^grandmother)`, but it's best because cookies are awesome.

Comment: I guess don't understand why you hash AND sort?  Your hash isn't guaranteed to be O(n) and the sorting may not be O(n log(n)) where n is the number of elements.  If you are not allowed to create any further data types and only compare, you will need to find the most efficient string comparing method and possibly employ tricks as a few have suggested.  If you aren't restricting on the creation of more data your best bet is a hash.  A binary tree of some kind might another one to do it.

Comment: @user1700184 what are you talking about? How is querying a HashSet O(1)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since this looks to me like a string algorithm, I'll assume for a moment that its not possible to sort this sequence (hence string) then you can use [Longest Common Sequence algorithm (LCS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)

Assuming the input size is constant, then the problem has a complexity of O(nxm), (length of the two inputs)

Comment: But why do a `O(n*m)` complicated solution when there are `O(n+m)` and `O(nlog(m))` ones? :|

Comment: @amit the dynamic programming solution takes O(n*m), which one takes O(n+m)? for O(nlog(m))  solution I assume you are talking about sorting, right? which is something I chose to ignore

Comment: How LCS will give intersection of 2 strings? We might miss out on many characters. for e.g. s1=[A B D C E F] and s2=[C D E F G H] here, LCS will be [D E F] while intersection of 2strings is [C D E F]! Am I missing something here?

Comment: srbh.kmr, no, you're not, that's the LCS. This is even a simpler example where the LCS doesn't work:
char[] A = {'a', 'b'};
char[] B = {'b', 'a'};
LCS gives either {'a'} or {'b'}, depending on the implementation, because it looks for a sequence of characters that appears in the same order in both arrays.

Comment: srbh.kmr, @Gabriel, I disagree with your example. this is not a shortcoming of LCS, but of your example(s), the two inputs simply have to share the exact common sequence in order to find a match. usually its run from left ti right, but you can do it in the other direction. the algorithm searches for the common sequence and just the common characters, so "one" has at most one letter match with "eno". This is what the algorithm does and not a disadvantage of it

Comment: LCS doesn't give the right answer for this problem, the algorithm works on string where the order matters, In this case the intersection  is always on sets, where order doesn't matter. The simple example of @Gabriel is right on the spot, we would need more assumptions on the input data for this to work. The hash answer is probably the best given the ordering constraint.

Comment: well as I explained in my answer,the assumption is that the OP is trying to find a pattern/substring in a certain string, and so the order matters, else the answer of @codaddict is the correct one

Comment: Well, the OP asked for the intersection between the two arrays. Intersection is a concept from set theory, and sets (by definition) not dependent on the order of its elements. I'm not saying that LCS is bad for some reason. I just claim it does not give you the intersection. It's an algorithm that solves a problem, but not the (set) intersection problem. If the arrays aren't to be considered as sets, then ok, but then you are probably not asking for a true intersection. But I understand the point of your assumption: if it's an array, it's more to a string than to a set.

Answer (score 109):

```
foreach element e in array A
    insert e into hash table H

foreach element e in array B
    if H contains e 
        print e
```

This algorithm is `O(N)` in time and `O(N)` in space.

To avoid the extra space, you can use the sorting based approach.

Comment: @Yola There isn’t a faster-than-O(n) solution; there can’t be.

Comment: This solution not always O(N)

Comment: Note that there is still an issue with duplicates (how to handle it was not specified in the question), but often you want to print each element `min{#occurances(A),#occurances(B)}` or just once, while this solution prints them `#occurances(B)` times

Comment: @Yola No. You can ensure that it is O(N) for limited domains. For non-limited domains you can still prove that it *almost certainly* is O(N), and you can even quantify that certainty.

Comment: @Yola: Assuming descent load balance for the hash table, the probability for getting the worst case is slim to none.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, it depends on hash table - load factors, collisions resolving etc. Iwould not be so sure with this structure

Comment: @Yola We can wax poetry all day long. But you said “not the fastest way” and this is wrong in practice (in the expected case it *is* the fastest solution) *and* in theory (if push comes to shove you can implement a schema that either makes non-linear performance *exceedingly* unlikely or even guarantees linear performance for a limited domain). Neither of these theoretically-perfect solutions is necessarily easy to ensure in typical use-cases, but then hashing is already the fastest solution for the typical use-case.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, ok, i think its fastest, +1

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, but calculate hash may take much time isnt it? And search in hash table takes O(logN).

Comment: @Yola No, search in a hash table takes O(1). How long calculating the hash takes depends on the key type but it’s usually not much slower than comparing two keys (which is required in a tree and in sorting). In particular, for simple `char` keys it’s very fast.

Comment: @Konrad Searches take O(n) time. Imagine a case where all elements have the same hash value, so you need to store them in a list.

Comment: to fix the duplicate prints just remove `ele` from `H` when you print it (and break out when it gets empty)

Comment: Everything takes O(1) time if you limit the size of the dataset.  Hash lookups are O(1) on dataset sizes up to some limit, but so is factoring into primes.  Hashes are fast due to a small constant not big O notation.

Comment: @Jakub Read the discussion we had up to this point. You can prevent such collisions. In the *expected* case (with very high probability), the *amortised* runtime is O(1) for a proper load factor. That is what matters. The worst-case time of O(N) for a single access is highly misleading for a general-purpose analysis.

Comment: This does not handle duplicates. If you look at my solution, it's near the same as your, just using a Map instead of Set.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Yakk is exactly right, O(1) hash lookups are a lie. To get a O(1) expected lookup time, calculating the hash function must also be O(1) amortised, meaning it must examine at most a constant number c of bits in each key on average. When more than 2^c distinct keys are added to a hashtable, no hash function can distinguish them all. If there are m2^c keys, a best-possible O(1) hash function will map m keys into each of the 2^c buckets, implying linear lookup times with a tiny constant, around 1/2^c.

Comment: @j_random_hacker This is very, **very** rarely relevant (but, I agree, it sometimes is). But if you insist on being pedantic here then I will acquiesce and must insist that lookup *is* O(1). Asymptotic performance analysis is performed on a theoretical machine which has elementary operations whose runtime is defined as O(1), including elementary integer operations. By implication, hash table lookup is O(1), regardless of whether you count number of hashing operations, number of comparisons or number of other operations. (continued …)

Comment: @j_random_hacker (continued) You *can* analyse the runtime as O(k) where k is the maximum length of the keys. This isn’t necessarily O(N) though (k is independent from N in the general case). Furthermore, what we were comparing here was (implicitly!) the performance of hash tables relative to other methods of implementing OP’s algorithm. And if you insist that hash table lookup is O(N) then you run into the same behaviour in comparison-based methods, so your complication of the analysis gains you nothing. O(1) lookup performance is not a lie, it’s a model. Can we now *please* bury this?

Comment: We are using a Hash which hides an iteration that equals an iteration to array. Hash has to iterate through itself before saying that "I already have this object" or "I donot have this object brother".

Answer (score 33):

The lower bound on efficiency is O(n) - you need to at least read all the elements.
Then there are several apporaches:

### Dumb simplest approach

Search for every element from array one in array two. Time complexity O(n^2).

### Sorting approach

You need to sort only array one, then search for elements from array two using binary search. Time complexity: sorting O(nlogn), searching O(n * logn) = O(nlogn), total O(nlogn).

### Hash approach

Create a hash table from array one elements. Search for elements form second table in the hash table. The time complexity depends on the hash function. You can achieve O(1) for searches in the optimal case (all elements will have different hash value), but O(n) in the worst case (all elements will have the same hash value). Total time complexity: O(n^x), where x is a factor of hash function efficiency (between 1 and 2).

Some hash functions are guaranteed to build a table with no collisions. But the building no longer takes strictly O(1) time for every element. It will be O(1) in most cases, but if the table is full or a collision is encountered, then the table needs to be rehashed - taking O(n) time. This happens not so often, much less frequently than clean adds. So the AMORTISED time complexity is O(1). We don't care about some of the adds taking O(n) time, as long as the majority of adds takes O(1) time.

But even so, in an extreme case, the table must be rehashed every single insertion, so the strict time complexity would be O(n^2)

Comment: There is no need in rehashing since the length of the array can be precalculated, and you can create the hash table of size `n * LF^-1`, where `LF` is your pre-determined load factor. The complexity is `O(1)` per op for any `LF < 1`, and not `O(n^LF)`, because the expected number of reads you will need is `E= 1 + 1*LF + 1*LF^2 + ... + 1*LF^n < CONSTANT` (sum of geometric series), so each op is `O(1)`. That said, the worst case of hash tables is still `O(n)` per op, but the average case will be `O(1)`

Comment: Also, sorting approach can be done in `O(NlogM)`, where N is the length of the longer array and M is the length of the shorter one.

Comment: @amit I agree, but rehash still be needed if there is a collision in the table.

Comment: If you assume rehashing solution for collisions (and not chaining or linear open addressing) - then yes. But it will be `O(n)` average case and not `O(n^LF)`.

Comment: @amit That's what I am saying. The O(n^x) is for the case where there is no rehashing and collisions are solved by chaining or by another method.

Comment: Providing the worst case of lookup without an analysis of the *likelihood* is misleading and useless (unless you are explicitly searching for vulnerabilities to malicious input). In fact, the likelihood of this happening by chance (with a well-designed hash table!) is so exceedingly small that it can be safely disregarded. Your answer makes it sound as if expected value of `x` is close to 1.5 (and uniformly distributed between 1 and 2) when in fact it’s very close to 1. The same is true for double hashing. I’ve forgotten how to analyse this but there is a formalism to prove this.

Comment: @Konrad I don't deny that. I just operate on strict time complexity, the worst case scenarios.

Comment: Rehashing concept was ignored in solution mentioned above by codadict.

Answer (score 20):

There are a few methods in some languages that I'm aware of that do exactly what you want, have you considered looking at some of these implementations?

PHP - [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);

>> green
   red
```

Java - [List.retainAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-)

```
Collection listOne = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("milan","dingo", "elpha", "hafil", "meat", "iga", "neeta.peeta"));
Collection listTwo = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("hafil", "iga", "binga", "mike", "dingo"));

listOne.retainAll( listTwo );
System.out.println( listOne );

>> dingo, hafil, iga
```

Comment: Python can do this as well with [sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection). I imagine many languages also have a set type that can handle this.

Comment: I can bet `retainAll` of an Arraylist (infact all of the List implementation in std java) does a O(n^2).

Answer (score 5):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] a = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
        char[] b = {'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
        System.out.println(intersect(a, b));
    }

    private static Set<Character> intersect(char[] a, char[] b) {
        Set<Character> aSet = new HashSet<Character>();
        Set<Character> intersection = new HashSet<Character>();
        for (char c : a) {
            aSet.add(c);
        }
        for (char c : b) {
            if (aSet.contains(c)) {
                intersection.add(c);
            }
        }
        return intersection;
    }
```

Comment: Performance will be slightly less than optimal, since you don't actualy need to create the second set just to check if it contains elements from the second one.

Comment: I would also check the size, if b is huge and a is small, your code will run slower checking over the larger set

Comment: @user1281385 But in this case, dealing with characters, `contains()` is always of O(1) complexity whatever the size of the set.

Answer (score 4):

```
int s[256] // for considering all ascii values, serves as a hash function

for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
s[i]=0;

char a[]={'a','b','c','d'};
char b[]={'c','d','e','f'};

for(int i=0;i<sizeof(a);i++)
{
   s[a[i]]++;
 }

 for(int i=0;i<sizeof(b);i++)//checker function
 {
     if(s[b[i]]>0)
       cout<<b[i]; 
  }


  complexity O(m+n);
  m- length of array a
  n- length of array b
```

Answer (score 3):

## Google Guava

There are already many good answers to this, but if you want the one-liner approach using a library for lazy-coding, I'd go with [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) (for Java) and its [`Sets.intersection`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#intersection(java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set)) method.

*<sup>(no compiler at hand, bear with me)</sup>*

```
char[] A = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
char[] B = {'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};

Set<Character> intersection = Sets.intersection(
    Sets.newHashSet<Character>(Chars.asList(a)),
    Sets.newHashSet<Character>(Chars.asList(b))
);
```

Obviously, this is assuming both arrays wouldn't have duplicates, in which case using a set data structure would make more sense and allow for this sort of operation more efficiently, especially if you don't start from an array of primitives from the start.

May or may not fit your use case, but sort of the no-brainer approach for the general case.

Answer (score 2):

1. Sort both the arrays.
2. Then do loop until they have have elements common Or one of the arrays reaches its end.

Asymptotically, this takes the complexity of sorting. i.e. O(NlogN) where N is the length of longer input array.

Comment: It can be improved to `O(NlogM)` (N is the length of the larger arra, M is the shorter) by sorting the shorter array alone, and iterating+binary searching each element in the longer array.

Answer (score 2):

If you care about duplicates, use a hash map to index list A, with the key being the element, and the value being a number of how many times that element has been seen.

You iterate through the first and for every element in A and if it does not exist in the map, put it in there with a value of 1, if it already exists in the map, add one to that value.

Next, iterate through B, and if the value exists, subtract 1. If not, put -1 in the value on the table for that element.

Finally, iterate through the map and for any element that has a value != 0, print out as a difference.

```
private static <T> List<T> intersectArrays(List<T> a, List<T> b) {
    Map<T, Long> intersectionCountMap = new HashMap<T, Long>((((Math.max(a.size(), b.size()))*4)/3)+1);
    List<T> returnList = new LinkedList<T>();
    for(T element : a) {
        Long count = intersectionCountMap.get(element);
        if (count != null) {
            intersectionCountMap.put(element, count+1);
        } else {
            intersectionCountMap.put(element, 1L);
        }
    }
    for (T element : b) {
        Long count = intersectionCountMap.get(element);
        if (count != null) {
            intersectionCountMap.put(element, count-1);
        } else {
            intersectionCountMap.put(element, -1L);
        }            
    }
    for(T key : intersectionCountMap.keySet()) {
        Long count = intersectionCountMap.get(key);
        if (count != null && count != 0) {
            for(long i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                returnList.add(key);
            }
        }
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

This should run in `O(n)`, as we're only iterating the Lists each once, and the Map once. The Data structures here used in Java should be efficient, as the `HashMap` is constructed with a capacity that can handle the largest size of the lists.

I'm using a `LinkedList` for the return as it provides us a way of adding and iterating through a list for our unknown sized intersection.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is not to start with arrays at all. Arrays are optimal for random access to elements, but not optimal for searching (which is what finding the intersection is all about). As you are talking about *intersection*, you must be regarding the arrays as sets. So use a more appropriate data structure (in Java, a `Set`). Then the task is much more efficient.

Comment: Depends. For a small number of data points (~ less than 15) arrays *are* the fastest data structure for searching.

Comment: … incidentally, `Set` in Java is an interface and can be implemented by a linear array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tree, but time will be O(n(log n)) and elements must be comparable

Comment: trees are very inefficient for constant data relative to sorting solutions. The main reason for it is cache - arrays are MUCH more cache efficient then trees. (Though it is `O(nlogn)`, same as sort and iterate, the hidden constants will be much higher)

Answer (score 1):

First, sort the two arrays using best sorting algorithm.
Then, with linear search, you can get the common elements.

If an extra space is provided then we can use hash table to do that.

Answer (score 1):

in ruby you can just say

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
b = ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
c = a & b
```

c contains ['c','d']

Answer (score 1):

Sort two arrays first, then iterate them, if they are the same element, add to to be returned array.

Code is here:

```
public static void printArr(int[] arr){
    for (int a:arr){
        System.out.print(a + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static int[] intersectionOf(int[] arr1, int[] arr2){
    Arrays.sort(arr1);
    Arrays.sort(arr2);

    printArr(arr1);
    printArr(arr2);

    int i=0, j=0, k=0;
    int[] arr = new int[Math.min(arr1.length, arr2.length)];

    while( i < arr1.length && j < arr2.length){
        if(arr1[i] < arr2[j]){
            i++;
        } else if(arr1[i] > arr2[j]){
            j++;
        } else {
            arr[k++] = arr1[i++];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return Arrays.copyOf(arr, k);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 6};
    int[] arr2 = {10, 2, 5, 1};
    printArr(intersectionOf(arr1,arr2));
}
```

outputs:

```
arr1: 1, 2, 6, 
arr2: 1, 2, 5, 10, 
arr: 1, 2,
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are dealing with ANSI characters. The approach should be similar for Unicode, just change the range.

```
char[] A = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
char[] B = {'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
int[] charset = new int[256]

for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
  charset[A[i]]++;
}
```

Now iterate over the B and you can check if the corresponding charset value for the character being iterated is greater than 0. You can store them in a list or any other collection.

This approach takes O(n) time complexity and a constant space for your checks not taking into account your new array/list being used to hold the common elements.

This is better than the HashSet/Hashtable approach in terms of space complexity.

Comment: The range of Unicode is (theoretically) 32 bits – that would require 16 GiB of RAM for your `charset` table. Do you see how why people used hash tables instead?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think it really depends on the problem and what trade-offs one is willing to make. If we are dealing with comparing terabytes of file then a fixed size charset table would be a more feasible approach if you want to stick to one machine.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The above case also beats the hash table approach any time if we know we are dealing with ASCII strings.

Comment: Keep dreaming. The Unicode array would be 4 GiB large. Even if we have sufficient RAM, the random access pattern would kill cache performance. A hash table will be faster.

Comment: For large data sets wouldn't insertions into hash table be O(n)? How would it be faster? I think a map-reduce approach may be a better approach for solving this problem when dealing with large data sets.

Comment: The problem with using an array is that it also no longer has O(1) access time – loading the relevant memory pages and caching on the processor will take a significant time. Hash table, because they take much less space, will have significantly better individual access times.

Comment: What you are suggesting is that the run time is no longer a function of the size of the input(n). However, in case of the hash table you will also need to store the hash for each character/string in the array. In the above case you would not need that. Arrays are stored sequentially and hence their access time would be constant. In case of hash table you would run into collisions very easily and depending on implementation would take O(n) for access in the worst case.

Comment: You are simply wrong, and I’ve already explained the reason. As the array becomes very large, it no longer fits into quickly accessible memory regions. As a consequence, parts of it need to be loaded from slower storage, which takes time (up to 1000 times as much time as a regular access!). The hash table does *not* run into this problem because it’s much (much, much!) smaller. Yes, you may get collisions but the expected number of collisions is still very low. because even very long text will only use few different characters. So finding an entry is, on average, still very fast.

Answer (score 0):

You could use HashSet in .NET 3.5 or later. Example c# code:

```
HashSet<int> set1 = new HashSet<int>(new int[]{8, 12, 13, 15});

HashSet<int> set2 = new HashSet<int>(new int[] { 15, 16, 7, 8, 9 });

set1.IntersectWith(set2);

foreach (int i in set1)

   Console.Write(i+ " ");
```

//output: 8 15

Answer (score 0):

Sort one of the arrays (m Log(m) )
now Pick each element from other array and 
do a binary search in first array(the sorted one)  ->n Log(m)

Total Time Complexity :- **(n+m)Log(m)**.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following would be useful. 
These are two different approached:

- Simple Intersection where you compare all the elements from one array
  to another array.
- Sorting and searching based approach which sorts one array and search second array element in first array using binary
  search.

`//`

```
public class IntersectionOfUnsortedArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr1 = { 12, 4, 17 };
        int[] arr2 = { 1, 12, 7, 17 };
        System.out.println("Intersection Using Simple Comparision");
        printArray(simpleIntersection(arr1, arr2));
        System.out.println("Intersection Using Sort and Binary Search");
        printArray(sortingBasedIntersection(arr1, arr2));
    }

    /*
     * Simple intersection based on the comparison without any sorting.
     * Complexity O(n^2)
     */
    public static int[] simpleIntersection(int[] a, int[] b) {
        int minlen = a.length > b.length ? b.length : a.length;
        int c[] = new int[minlen];
        int k=0;
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++){
                if(a[i]==b[j]){
                    c[k++]=a[i];
                }
            }
        }
        int arr[] = new int[k];
        // copy the final array to remove unwanted 0's from the array c
        System.arraycopy(c, 0, arr, 0, k);
        return arr;
    }

    /*
     * Sorting and Searching based intersection.
     * Complexity Sorting O(n^2) + Searching O(log n)
     */

    public static int[] sortingBasedIntersection(int[] a, int[] b){
        insertionSort(a);
        int minlen = a.length > b.length ? b.length : a.length;
        int c[] = new int[minlen];
        int k=0;
        for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
            int result = binarySearch(a,0,a.length,b[i]);
            if(result > -1){
                c[k++] = a[result];
            }
        }
        int arr[] = new int[k];
        // copy the final array to remove unwanted 0's from the array c
        System.arraycopy(c, 0, arr, 0, k);
        return arr;
    }

    public static void insertionSort(int array[]) {
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            int j = i;
            int b = array[i];
            while ((j > 0) && (array[j - 1] > b)) {
                array[j] = array[j - 1];
                j--;
            }
            array[j] = b;
        }
    }

    static int binarySearch(int arr[], int low, int high, int num) {
        if (high < low)
            return -1;
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (num == arr[mid])
            return mid;
        if (num > arr[mid])
            return binarySearch(arr, (mid + 1), high, num);
        else
            return binarySearch(arr, low, (mid - 1), num);
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] array) {
        for (int value : array) {
            System.out.print(" "+value);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the collections are already sorted, as shown in the question, then the best solution (not mentioned yet) is a merge-sort-like algorithm that runs in O(n+m).

Compare the first elements of each collection. If they're the same, add the element to the intersection set and pop both elements from their collections. If the elements are different, pop the element that's greater, in comparison, to the other element. Repeat until one collection is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 features, here is an algorithm which honours duplicates within a list instead of turning a list into a set. No sorting, so no `n log n`.

1. Convert one of the lists into a map, with value being number of occurrences (cost: O(n)).
2. For each item in the other list, if the item exists in the map, decrease occurrence by one (cost: O(n)).

Therefore, overall cost is O(n). Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Dup {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> listA = Arrays.asList(3, 1, 4, 1, 9, 5, 9);
    List<Integer> listB = Arrays.asList(2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 8, 9, 7, 9, 3, 2, 3);
    findCommons(listA, listB);
  }

  static void findCommons(List<Integer> listA, List<Integer> listB) {
    Map<Integer, Long> mapA = 
        listA.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(Integer::intValue, Collectors.counting()));

    List<Integer> commons = new ArrayList<>();
    listB.stream()
        .filter(e -> mapA.get(e) != null)
        .filter(e -> mapA.get(e) > 0)
        .forEach(e -> {
            mapA.put(e, mapA.get(e) - 1);
            commons.add(e);
        });

    System.out.println(commons);
  }
}
```

Code above will give this output: `[5, 3, 9, 9]`.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;

public class arraycommon {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    // display common element in two diffrent array
    int sizea,sizeb,i=0,j=0,k=0;
    int count=0;
    System.out.println("enter the size array A:"+'\n');
    sizea=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter the size array B"+'\n');
    sizeb=sc.nextInt();
    int a[]=new int[sizea];
    int b[]=new int[sizeb];
    int c[]=new int[sizea];


    System.out.println("enter the element in array A:"+'\n');
    for (i = 0; i < sizea; i++) {

        a[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("enter the element in array B:"+'\n');
    for (i = 0; i < sizeb; i++) {

        b[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("the element in array A:"+'\n');
    for (i = 0; i < sizea; i++) {

        System.out.print(a[i]+" ");

    }
    System.out.println('\n');
    System.out.println("the element in array B:"+'\n');
    for (i = 0; i < sizeb; i++) 
    {

        System.out.print(b[i]+" ");
    }

    for (i = 0; i <sizea; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < sizeb; j++) 
        {
           if(a[i]==b[j])
           {
               count++;
               c[k]=a[i];
               k=k+1;
           }
        }
    }
    System.out.println('\n');
    System.out.println("element common in array is");

    if(count==0)
    {
        System.out.println("sorry no common elements");
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i <count; i++) 
        {

        System.out.print(c[i]+" ");
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Some explanation of the code would make this answer more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
    simply search each element of first array with each element of second array and stored matched result in third array
class Union
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  char a[] ={'f','g','d','v','a'};
  char b[] ={'a','b','c','d','e'};
  char temp[] = new char[5];
  int p=0;
  for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++)
    {
      if(a[i]==b[j])     //searches if both array has common element
      {

        temp[p] = a[i];   //if match found store it in a new array
        p++;
      }

    }

  }
  for(int k=0;k<temp.length;k++)
  {
      System.out.println(temp[k]);
  }

  }
}
```

Comment: This is brute force method, not very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my solution with test data

```
public class IntersectionOf2Arrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("2 Given Arrays are \n");
        int[] x= {2,5,3,7};
        //int[] x= {3, 10, 4, 2, 8};
        int[] y={5,2,9,0,1,3};
        //int[] y={10, 4, 12, 3, 23, 1, 8};
        Arrays.stream(x).forEach(a -> System.out.print("  "+a));
        System.out.print("\n");
        Arrays.stream(y).forEach(b -> System.out.print("  "+b));
        System.out.print("\nIntersection of above two  array is ");
        int[] result = intersection(x,y);
        Arrays.stream(result).forEach(c -> System.out.print("  "+c));
    }
    static int[] intersectionWithFilter(int x[],int y[]){

        int[] z =Arrays.stream(x)
                .distinct()
                .filter(a -> Arrays.stream(y).anyMatch(b -> b==a))
                .toArray();
        return z;
    }

    static int[] intersection(int x[],int y[]) {
        int len = 0;
        if(x.length>y.length)
            len = x.length;
        else
            len=y.length;

        int []z=new int[len];
        int c = 0;
        for(int i=0;i <(x.length);i++) {
            for(int j=0;j < y.length;j++) {
                if(x[i]==y[j]){
                    z[c]=x[i];
                    c++;
                }
                else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        // As it is int array so it is by default 0 filled , so we need to remove those zeros
        return resize(z,c);
    }

    private static int[] resize(int[] oldArray, int newSize) {
        int[] newArray = new int[newSize];
        System.arraycopy( oldArray, 0, newArray, 0, newSize );
        return newArray;
    }
}
```

Test result is below:-
2 Given Arrays are
2  5  3  7
Second array
5  2  9  0  1  3
Intersection of above two  array is   2  5  3