# Java Render Only Intersecting?

Tags: java, render, slick2d

So I was wondering how to run through a multi-dimensional array without having to use for loops to test whether or not the objects are intersecting in a rectangle and then render the interesting?

Currently I'm using two for loops to go through it and within the nested loop I have to use the `intersecting()` method and since this needs to happen every frame my game is getting low FPS. I assume it's because I have 650x350 entities in my array. I'll show the code below and restate the question. So my official question is how do I test whether or not an entity is intersecting with my rectangle camera so that it doesn't lag the game?

```
for (int x = 0; x < entities.length; x++) // entities.length is 650
{
   for (int y = 0; y < entities[0].length; y++) // entities[0].length is 350
   {
      if (camera.intersecting(entities[x][y]))
      {
         entities[x][y].render(g); // X and Y indices are multiplied by 32 to get the position
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: you can check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270491/best-way-to-find-an-intersection-between-two-arrays

Comment: Do the location and size of entities have a correlation with their place in the array?

Comment: Yes, each index is multiplied by the width/height to get the position.

Comment: Also, the world is scaled out to 0.8f

Answer (score 1):

This depends quite a bit on the mechanics of your game. But in a general sense I will recommend looking into Quadtrees ( http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). Then check which nodes your camera overlaps and draw their contents.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into this problem awhile ago, I made my render function use the camera's x, y, width, and height values to determine where to render by changing the starting positions of the for loops.

```
public void render(Camera camera, Graphics g) {
    // --------------------------------------------------------- //
    // Optimized rendering function to only draw what the camera //
    // can see                                                   //
    // --------------------------------------------------------- //
    int minX = toTileX(camera.getX());
    int minY = toTileY(camera.getY());
    int maxX = toTileX(camera.getX()) + toTileX(camera.getViewWidth());
    int maxY = toTileY(camera.getY()) + toTileY(camera.getViewHeight());

    for (TiledLayer l : layers) {
        for (int y = minY; y < maxY + 1; y++) {
            if (y < height && y >= 0) {
                for (int x = minX; x < maxX + 1; x++) {
                    if (x < width && x >= 0) {
                        Tile tile       = l.getTile(x, y);
                        TileSheet sheet = null;

                        try {
                            sheet = tileSheets.get(tile.getTileSetId());
                        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        Image image = sheet.getImage(tile.getTileId());

                        g.drawImage(image,
                                    x * tileWidth,
                                    y * tileHeight,
                                    (x * tileWidth) + tileWidth,
                                    (y * tileHeight) + tileHeight,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    tileWidth,
                                    tileHeight);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great but I scale out in my game, I'm using the Slick2D library, and if I try scaling then nothing gets rendered. I don't know how Slick2D translates locations based on scale so can anyone help? My scale is 0.8