# How to get the intersection between two array using java?

Tags: java

```
public Set intersection(Set set){

Set intersect = new Set(this.count + set.count);

for(int i=1; i<count; i++)
{

   if(this.items[i] && set.items[i])
   intersect.add(i);

return intersect;
}
```

Comment: Topic of this question says 'array' but the code says 'set'. What is this question about?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to find an intersection between two arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270491/best-way-to-find-an-intersection-between-two-arrays)

Answer (score 2):

To find the intersection of two sets you can use the function [retainAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29).

```
Set<Integer> s1;
Set<Integer> s2;
s1.retainAll(s2);
```

After this, `s1` will contain the intersection.

You could also use this method for arrays if you don't mind converting them to a set or list first, e.g.:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
Set<Integer> mySet = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(a));
```