# How to print common elements in 2 arrays without sorted output in Java

Tags: java, arrays, hashset

Given two arrays, find the common elements in them.

Example: `[1,45,33,23,22,45,233,21], [5,23,45,0,9,23,1,9]` => Output: `[1,45, 23]`

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Mycode {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a[] = {1, 45, 33, 23, 22, 45, 233, 21};
        int b[] = {5, 23, 45, 0, 9, 45, 1, 9};

        Mycode test = new Mycode();

        test.testNumber(a, b);
    }

    void testNumber(int c[], int d[]) {

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(d));
        Set<Integer> hset = new HashSet<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {
                if (c[i] == d[j]) {
                    System.out.println(c[i]);
                    hset.add(c[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(hset);
    }
}
```

Actual Output: `[1, 45, 33, 23, 22, 4, 233, 21] [5, 23, 45, 0, 9, 5, 1, 9]` =>
`[1, 23, 45]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the intersection between two arrays as a new array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270491/how-do-i-get-the-intersection-between-two-arrays-as-a-new-array)

Comment: @icarumbas I wouldn't say that this is a duplicate because it involves preserving the order of the output elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) makes no guarantees of the preservation of the insertion order as indicated in the JavaDoc:

> It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.

So I would prefer using a [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html). This Set implementation guarantees the preservation of the insertion order. From the JavaDocs:

> This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in
>   which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order)

```
void testNumber(int c[], int d[]) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(d));

    Set<Integer> hset = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {
            if (c[i] == d[j]) {
                hset.add(c[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(hset);
}
```

Output:

> [1, 45, 23]

Comment: Thanks Juan Carlos. I really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 
    HashMap
Loop through the first array and add each element with the value false.
Loop through the second and if it's in the hashMap then it's common.

Comment: HashSet maybe ?

Comment: HashSet, HashMap, TreeMap. In this case it's all the same since getting or adding and element from/ to the map has O(1) time complexity.

Comment: HashMap and TreeMap hold two elements Key and Value. What do you think he should use for second element?

Comment: My initial thought was to use HashMap, but you are right. If he needs only the common elements than HashSet is the best.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like below? This will be more neat since you don't need to have two for loops, and you don't need to sort it before hand.

```
public class Mycode {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Integer a[] = {1, 45, 33, 23, 22, 45, 233, 21};
        Integer b[] = {5, 23, 45, 0, 9, 45, 1, 9};

        Mycode test = new Mycode();

        System.out.println(test.testNumber(a, b));
    }

    public  <T> Set<T>  testNumber(T [] arra1, T [] arr2){
        Set<T> set1 = new HashSet<T>();
        Set<T> interset = new HashSet<T>();

        Collections.addAll(set1, arra1);
        for(T t: arr2){
            if(set1.contains(t))
                interset.add(t);
        }
        return interset;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array1));
list.retainAll(Arrays.asList(array2));
System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with time complexity of order N

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // write your code here

        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n1 = scn.nextInt();
        int[] arr1 = new int[n1];
        for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
            arr1[i] = scn.nextInt();
        }
        int n2 = scn.nextInt();
        int[] arr2 = new int[n2];
        for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
            arr2[i] = scn.nextInt();
        }
        HashMap < Integer, Integer > freqMap1 = new HashMap < > ();

        for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
            int ch = arr1[i];

            if (freqMap1.containsKey(ch)) {
                int f = freqMap1.get(ch);
                freqMap1.put(ch, f + 1);
            } else {
                freqMap1.put(ch, 1);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
            int ch = arr2[i];

            if (freqMap1.containsKey(ch)) {
                System.out.println(ch);
                freqMap1.remove(ch);
            }
        }

    }

}
```