# How can I take objects from the second set of objects which don't exist in the first set of objects in fast way?

Tags: c#

I have records in two databases. That is the entity in the first database:

```
public class PersonInDatabaseOne
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

That is the entity in the second database:

```
public class PersonInDatabaseTwo
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get records from the second database which don't exist in the first database (the first name and the last name must be different than in the first database). Now I have something like that but that is VERY SLOW, too slow:

```
List<PersonInDatabaseOne> peopleInDatabaseOne = new List<PersonInDatabaseOne>();
// Hear I generate objects but in real I take it from database:
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    peopleInDatabaseOne.Add(new PersonInDatabaseOne { Name = "aaa" + i, Surname = "aaa" + i });
}


List<PersonInDatabaseTwo> peopleInDatabaseTwo = new List<PersonInDatabaseTwo>();
// Hear I generate objects but in real I take it from database:
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    peopleInDatabaseTwo.Add(new PersonInDatabaseTwo { FirstName = "aaa" + i, LastName = "aaa" + i });
}
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    peopleInDatabaseTwo.Add(new PersonInDatabaseTwo { FirstName = "bbb" + i, LastName = "bbb" + i });
}


List<PersonInDatabaseTwo> peopleInDatabaseTwoWhichNotExistInDatabaseOne = new List<PersonInDatabaseTwo>();

// BELOW CODE IS VERY SLOW:
foreach (PersonInDatabaseTwo personInDatabaseTwo in peopleInDatabaseTwo)
{
    if (!peopleInDatabaseOne.Any(x => x.Name == personInDatabaseTwo.FirstName && x.Surname == personInDatabaseTwo.LastName))
    {
        peopleInDatabaseTwoWhichNotExistInDatabaseOne.Add(personInDatabaseTwo);
    }
};
```

Comment: For heavy searching then `HashSet<T>` is much faster than `List<T>`.

Comment: Check out `Enumerable.Except` method.

Comment: If dataset is very big and performance are really critical then you may start your own study from [this small comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25566838/1207195)

Comment: I can't use hashset because I have entities differnt ttypes in two databases and they have much more properties than only firstname and lastname....

Comment: But if you have a database then why don't you do this job in SQL?   Engine will use indices...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: with respect to the comments - using a real model and a dictionary instead of a simple set:

Try hashing your list into a Dictionary to hold your people objects, as the key - try a Tuple instead of a name1==name2 && lname1==lname2.

This will potentially then look like this:

```
// Some people1 and people2 lists of models already exist:
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var removeThese = people1.Select(x=>Tuple.Create(x.FirstName,x.LastName));
var dic2 = people2.ToDictionary(x=>Tuple.Create(x.Name,x.Surname),x=>x);
var result =  dic2.Keys.Except(removeThese).Select(x=>dic2[x]).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think you need to start the stopwatch before building the HashSet objects for benchmarking purpose, because their construction is a part of the algorithm used to diff between the lists.

Comment: I can't use Except because I have entities differnt types in two databases and they have much more properties than only firstname and lastname

Comment: You would do better to hash the results, and use Except anyway.. by for example using a Dictionary - with the key as above - and the value a real model. Admittedly this will take some additional space, but I see no better solution.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way is dependent on the number of entities, and what indexes you already have.

- If there's a few entities, what you already have performs better because multiple scans of a small set takes less than creating `HashSet` objects.
- **If all of your entities fit in the memory**, the best way is to build `HashSet` out of them, and use `Except` which is detailed nicely by @alex.feigin.
- If you can't afford loading all entities in the memory, you need to divide them into bulks *based on the comparison key* and load them into memory and apply the `HashSet` method repeatedly. Note that bulks can't be based on the number of records, but on the comparison key. For example, load all entities with names starting with `'A'`, then `'B'`, and so on.
- If you already have an index on the database on the comparison key (like, in your case, `FirstName` and `LastName`) in one of the databases, you can retrieve a sorted list from the database. This will help you do binary search (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) on the sorted list for comparison. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh(v=vs.110).aspx
- If you already have an index on the database on the comparison key **on both databases**, you can get to do this in O(n), and in a scalable way (any number of records). You need to loop through both lists and find the differences only once. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/161535/187996 for more details.