# How to compare two List<int> and output the number of identical values?

Tags: c#

I have two List in which color IDs are stored.
I need to compare List  **adress1PlayerColorList** and List  **bufferPropertyList** and if there are the same values, then increase the variable int **SameColorsCount**.
For example, I have two identical values in adress1PlayerColorList and bufferPropertyList, how can I make it so that after checking two Lists, my SameColorsCount value gives the number of identical elements?

```
        int adress1PlayerColor = new int();
        List<int> adress1PlayerColorList = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < adress1Player.Count; i++)
        {
            adress1PlayerColor = boardInstance.PropertyColor(adress1Player[i]);
            adress1PlayerColorList.Add(adress1PlayerColor);
            
        }

        ArrayList bufferProperty = playerManager.RequestPlayerProperties(indexNextPlayer);
        List<int> bufferPropertyList = new List<int>();
        int PlayerOwnPropertyColor = new int();
        for (int i = 0; i < bufferProperty.Count; i++)
        {
            PlayerOwnPropertyColor = boardInstance.PropertyColor((int)bufferProperty[i]);
            bufferPropertyList.Add(PlayerOwnPropertyColor);
            

        }
```

Comment: I've removed the `[visual-studio]` tag because this question isn't about using the Visual Studio application, and I've removed the `[unity3d]` tag because nothing in this question relates to Unity.

Comment: [FYI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31069992/3181933).

Comment: What are you trying to do? Where did these values come from? If you have to compare lists of objects you may be able to use `IntersectBy` instead of extracting the object IDs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have a List <int> A and List <int> B - which stores the color IDs. I receive a request from List <int> A, I have to check how many identical colors there are in List <int> A and List <int> B and output their number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-6.0) to find the common items in any `IEnumerable<T>`, not just lists. LINQ provides methods for all set operations like Except, Intersect, Union, Concat :

```
var common =list1.Intersect(list2);
```

`Intersect` and the other set operations depended on object equality to determine whether two items match. That's OK for a `List<int>` but not very helpful for eg a `Player` class where equality depends on an `Id`.

**IntersectBy**

.NET(Core) 6 introduced [IntersectBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersectby?view=net-6.0) and other similar methods that allow you to specify a property to compare for equality, eg :

```
var common=players1.IntersectBy(players2,x=>x.Id);
```

This means that instead of eg extracting the color IDs from a `List<Color>` to find the common colors, you can now use :

```
var commonColors=firstPlayer.Colors.IntersectBy(secondPlayer.Colors,x=>x.Id);
```